# Cannot resolve pursuing guards / companions glitch even though I've paid all my bounties

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

OK so I look through the Internet and found that the fast travel/wait/rest glitch thing could be solved by paying off bounties or dealing with Farkas **but** I've gone to every hold to purposefully got in trouble and pay off all bounties and I've talked with Farkas to make sure he wouldn't follow me and he didn't.

**So now I have no bounties and the companions aren't following me but I still experience the glitch! Any pointers?** I also tried restarting my XBox and unplugging it, the bug is still there.... Help! Walking everywhere is annoying!

Comment: what is the problem - that while Farkas doesn't follow you other guards do? Which guards follow you?